# Avoid logging on strdout and stderr while using RotatingFileHandler Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, python-logging

I've a little problem:
I wrote a module with a function that sets a RotatingFileHandler, everething works fine (other inclusions, etc)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import logging, os, traceback
import logging.handlers
from pathlib import Path
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from legacy.stuff.EnvironmentApplicationHandler import EnvironmentApplicationHandler

def getLoggerFromEnv(filename=None):

    try:
        logFile = EnvironmentApplicationHandler.getEnv('LOGFILENAME')
        #nel caso non esista la directory, viene creata
        listFolder = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(logFile))
        Path(listFolder[0]).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

        if not logFile:
            raise ValueError("File LOGFILENAME non definito")
        Formatter = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(name)s] - %(message)s"
        MaxBytes = 10240000
        backupCount = 10
        if filename:
            if os.path.isfile(filename):
                with open(filename, "r") as f:
                    for line in f:
                        if "Format" in line:
                            Formatter = line.split('=')[1]

                        if "MaxBytes" in line:
                            MaxBytes = int(line.split('=')[1])

                        if "backupCount" in line:
                            backupCount = int(line.split('=')[1])

        log = logging.getLogger('')

        handler = RotatingFileHandler(logFile, maxBytes=MaxBytes, backupCount= backupCount)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(Formatter)

        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        log.addHandler(handler)

        return log

    except ValueError as e:
        raise RuntimeError(e)
    except Exception as e:
        raise RuntimeError(traceback.format_exc())
```

Then im trying this function on a simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from shared.utility.logger import getLoggerFromEnv
import logging

try:
    log = getLoggerFromEnv()
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log.debug("loggin 10 44")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

log.debug("TESTING LOG")
```

My problem is that, when i run the script, evering is displayed on the stdout and on my RotatingFileHandler, I would like to avoid this problem

[image: required values]

[image: run script]
as you can see, on the console i can see the log lines, and on my file **rotatingFile.out**, there are the same lines

**rotatingFile.out**

[image: rotatingFile.out]

**NB:** everething works fine

Comment: I've tested your code (just overriding the `logFile = EnvironmentApplicationHandler.getEnv('LOGFILENAME')` line) and its working as expected: logging only to the rotating file.

Comment: @cr_alberto, it works if you run the script by the console?

Comment: Yep. As a hint, note that your console output is not formatted, so there might be some untracked console logger doing that extra output. I can't reproduce the issue on my environment.